# Client side pagination is slow

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

For a record set of 10000 rows just a window of a few hundred rows
is subscribed via start row,stop row, takes over 10 seconds  to show "ready" ? Should all records be removed before moving the window ? Why is meteor slow ?

Comment: Meteor.subscribe('querydata',Session.get("queryid"),Session.get("startrow"),Session.get("stoprow")  ,{
  onReady: function () { 
     console.log("READY NOW");
      Session.set("selected_query_data",Session.get("queryid"));
      console.log("find ALL start DATA done" + queryData.find({}).count());
  },
  onError: function () { console.log("onError", arguments); }
});

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you are only publishing the keys you really need and not those you don't. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('queryData',function(queryId,startRow,stopRow){
  return queryData.find({ ... query ...},{ fields: {name: 1, description: 1}});
});
```

This is especially important if your documents are big.

Secondly, look at the websocket traffic in your browser's inspector to see how much data you are actually sending over in the publication.

Thirdly, make sure your collection is indexed on the keys you are searching on so that you are not doing collection scans.

Meteor is generally pretty fast but simple mistakes can make it feel very slow.

Comment: simply avoiding minimongo worked, request the array and push that to the table engine avoids minimongo I/O, great speed.